# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have tried to search for an answer but my results have not been fruitful.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order' at line 1

And the script I'm running is:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Thu 12 Oct 2017 01:11:28 PM EDT
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0    
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema customer
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- This schema was created for a stub table

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema customer
--
-- This schema was created for a stub table
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `customer` ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Product` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cost` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `price` INT NULL,
  `catagory` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `stock` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customer` (
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `customer_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `zip` INT NULL,
  `credit_card` BIGINT(17) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  `shipping_date` DATE NULL,
  `completed` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `urgent_order` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `vip` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `quantity` INT NULL,
  `product_id` INT NULL,
  `repeat_order` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `customer_customer_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Order_customer1_idx` (`customer_customer_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_customer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_customer_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customer` (`customer_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`review`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`review` (
  `review_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` INT NULL,
  `review` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `order_id` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  `Product_product_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  INDEX `fk_review_Product1_idx` (`Product_product_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_review_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_product_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Product` (`product_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Order_has_Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order_has_Product` (
  `Order_id` INT NULL,
  `Product_product_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_id`, `Product_product_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Order_has_Product_Product1_idx` (`Product_product_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Order_has_Product_Order1_idx` (`Order_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_has_Product_Order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Order_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Order` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_has_Product_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_product_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Product` (`product_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `customer` ;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Have you tried manually executing it one step at a time to determine which step breaks?

Comment: I tried running just the table creation commands on db-fiddle.com, and got an error because the FK id fields in `Order_has_Product` are listed as NULLable, but are also the parts of a composite foreign key. Can't say that's the problem you're hitting, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I changed the keys to unique and no luck

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you still have an error with the following script ?

change :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order_has_Product` (
  `Order_id` INT{+ NOT+} NULL,
  `Product_product_id` INT{+ NOT+} NULL,
```

(it work on my MySQL 5.7, I don't have any mariadb to try now)

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Thu 12 Oct 2017 01:11:28 PM EDT
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0    
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema customer
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- This schema was created for a stub table

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema customer
--
-- This schema was created for a stub table
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `customer` ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Product` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cost` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `price` INT NULL,
  `catagory` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `stock` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customer` (
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `customer_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `zip` INT NULL,
  `credit_card` BIGINT(17) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  `shipping_date` DATE NULL,
  `completed` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `urgent_order` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `vip` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `quantity` INT NULL,
  `product_id` INT NULL,
  `repeat_order` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `customer_customer_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Order_customer1_idx` (`customer_customer_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_customer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_customer_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customer` (`customer_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`review`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`review` (
  `review_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` INT NULL,
  `review` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `order_id` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  `Product_product_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  INDEX `fk_review_Product1_idx` (`Product_product_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_review_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_product_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Product` (`product_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Order_has_Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order_has_Product` (
  `Order_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_id`, `Product_product_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Order_has_Product_Product1_idx` (`Product_product_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Order_has_Product_Order1_idx` (`Order_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_has_Product_Order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Order_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Order` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_has_Product_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_product_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Product` (`product_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `customer` ;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: I've verified that this works on MariaDB 10.2. I guess what is different here is that `Order_has_Product.Product_product_id INT` is defined as `NOT NULL`.